# Helper method for Bitmap and disposing correctly C#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have a helper method that creates a bitmap with its own using statement. Originally I had the issue of when returning the object controlled by using statement it would be disposed once scope was left.. So, with the help of this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bf58b39c-f643-4e2e-8185-347c947a3e86/image-getrawformat-or-getwidth-throw-parameter-is-not-valid?forum=winforms), I was able to figure out that was my issue as well.

So I return a cloned version and pass it to DrawImage of the Graphics class like so,

```
g.DrawImage(getInputDataImage(dr.DRODAT, oFont, 430, 87, black, white, Color.Transparent), new Point(280, 23)); //DATE
```

getInputDataImage:

```
 public static Image getInputDataImage(...
 {
        using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        using(var format = new StringFormat{Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})
        {
            //set coordinates on canvas to put barcode
            Point point = new Point(50, 50);

            RectangleF layoutRectangle = new RectangleF(new PointF(0, 0), new SizeF(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
            graphics.Clear(color);
            graphics.DrawString(text, font, fontBrush, layoutRectangle, format);

            return (Bitmap)bitmap.clone();
        }

 }
```

Will DrawImage call dispose in it's destructor on the classes it uses? How should I handle disposing the Bitmap class when used like this? There is a few cases where I call the getInDataImage helper method with a new object being returned each time. Trying to understand how to maintain disposing this way.

Is it better to return the original object from the helper and not wrap it in a using statement, and handle its disposing in the main method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try returning the bitmap object itself from the helper method without the "using" statement and without cloning it.

In your caller, create a new object then dispose:

```
using(Bitmap b = getInputDataImage(...))
{
    g.DrawImage(b, new Point(...));
    // Do anything else I need to do with "b"
}
// "b" is now disposed of, I can't use it here
```

When you use the "using", you dispose of the object once the code exits those brackets. So when you create an object, you want it alive while you use it, then you want to dispose of it.

The best way to handle this is in the highest level possible. It makes sense to dispose of the Graphics object in your helper method because it never leaves the scope of that method. However, the Bitmap you want DOES leave that method, so you don't want to dispose of it until after it gets used by its caller. So then, logically, the caller would be responsible for disposing of it.

Comment: Ah okay, so if I do, lets say 5 different calls to g.DrawImage(getInputDataImage()) the proper way would to provide a using statement as shown above for each one?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. Remember, if it makes more sense, you don't have to use the "using" statement. You can call the Bitmap's "Dispose()" method.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. It is more clear now.